# Managing an OpenLayers Map in a React Tab Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, frontend, openlayers

I'm building a SPA app with a navigation bar with various tabs. When a tab is selected, I dispatch an action through redux, and the `AppBody` component rerenders itself according to which tab is selected (see `renderAppBody()` in `AppBody`).

My issue is that one of the tabs must contain an OpenLayers map. I had a lot of trouble getting the map to mount in the first place as it must target an element that already exists on the DOM. I did this by overriding `componentDidMount`:

**MapBody.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import "ol/ol.css"
import Map from 'ol/map'
import View from 'ol/view'
import Tile from 'ol/layer/tile'
import OSM from 'ol/source/osm'

import "../../sass/App.scss";


var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new Tile({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 4
  })
});


const MapBody = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<div id="map"></div>);
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    map.setTarget("map");
  }
});

export default MapBody;
```

This means that whenever I switch tabs, my Map element is destroyed / removed and replaced with the content for the next tab. The effect is that the first time I select the map tab it renders, but if I then select another tab and then reselect the map tab the map will not render.

Is my approach inherently flawed for the outcome that I want? This is my first largish React project, so I'm unsure of the best way to engineer this behavior.

**Should I:**

- Maintain a reference to the map item and reappend it on rerender? (seems problematic)
- Hide tabs instead of replacing them? (also seems problematic)
- Make MapBody have two states: `visible` and `inactive`. Then always render it to the screen, and hiding it with CSS based on its state (seems hacky)
- Something more elegant?

**AppBody.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Activity from '../components/body/Activity'
import CategoryBody from '../components/body/CategoryBody'
import MapBody from '../components/body/MapBody'
import Search from '../components/body/Search'

import tabs from "../actions/tabDefinitions.js"

import "../sass/App.scss";

function renderAppBody(activeTab) {
  switch (activeTab) {
    case tabs.T_CATEGORIES:
      return <CategoryBody />
    case tabs.T_MAP:
      return (<MapBody />)
    case tabs.T_SEARCH:
      return <Search />
    case tabs.T_ACTIVITY:
      return <Activity />
    default:
      return <div>Oops! Something went wrong :(</div>
  }
}

const AppBody = ({activeTab}) => (
  <div className="frame_wrapper">
      {renderAppBody(activeTab)}
  </div>
)


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  activeTab: state.activeTab,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppBody);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up always adding the `MapBody` component to `AppBody` regardless of the selected tab. I then added an `active` prop to `MapBody` to add show / hide CSS classes. That way the map container is never removed / reset when the tab is changed, so the state is maintained nicely. My approach doesn't feel particularly elegant (read: it's a dirty, dirty hack), but it works nonetheless.

My `MapBody` render function became:

```
render: function () {
    return (<div id="map"
                 className={this.props.active ? "active_map" : "inactive_map"}>
            </div>);
}
```

by adding the following CSS *mostly* gave the desired behavior:

```
.inactive_map {
   display: none;
}
```

This caused the map container to be properly rendered / hidden when switching tabs, but the map canvas was gray and didn't render any content. To fix this, I overrode the `componentDidUpdate()` to call [`map.updateSize()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#updateSize), which forces a recalculation of the map viewport size. Final code:

**MapBody.js**

```
const MapBody = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (<div id="map"
                 className={this.props.active ? "active_map" : "inactive_map"}>
            </div>);
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.props.map.setTarget("map");
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function () {
    this.props.map.updateSize();
  }
});
```

**AppBody.js**

```
function renderAppBody(activeTab) {
  switch (activeTab) {
    case tabs.T_CATEGORIES:
      return <CategoryBody />
    case tabs.T_MAP:
      return "";
    case tabs.T_SEARCH:
      return <Search />
    case tabs.T_ACTIVITY:
      return <Activity />
    default:
      return (<div>Oops! Something went wrong :(</div>)
  }
}

const AppBody = ({activeTab}) => (
  <div className="frame_wrapper">
      {renderAppBody(activeTab)}
      <Map active={activeTab == tabs.T_MAP}/>
  </div>
)
```